# To find the constants of a function which is analytic

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, cauchy-riemann-equations

Find the real constants $a,b,c,d$ so that the function is analytic.
$f(z)=x^2+axy+by^2+ i(cx^2+dxy+y^2)$

I know that,since the given function is analytic,we can use cauchy reimann equations to solve this, I got :

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = 2x + ay \\$$

$$\frac{\partial v}{\partial y} = 2y + xd \\$$

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = ax + 2by \\$$

$$\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} = 2cx + yd$$

I know that we have to equate this but even though I equate I get an equation not a solution for the constants. At last I got $a=d$ and $c=d$
I don't know whether this is right or wrong, could you please help me?

Comment: Alternative method: $f$ must be of the form $(p+iq)(x+iy)^2$ i.e. $p=1,-p=b,a=-2q,q=c,-q=1,d=2p.$

Answer (score 1):

You must have $u_x=v_y$ and $u_y=-v_x$, hence:
$$\begin{cases}2x+ay=2y+dx \\ ax+2by=-2cx-dy\end{cases}$$
From the first equation you get $a=d=2$, can you take it from here?

Comment: I think it's silly but could you please explain how you got $a=d=2$?

Comment: @JeonjungkookKookie you must have $2x=dx$ and $ay=2y$

Comment: ohh we have to equate the x coefficients and y coefficients! Thank you so much