# Finding real constants of the function which are analytic

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, cauchy-riemann-equations

Find the real constants a,b,c such that  the function is analytic
$f(z)=r^2a\cos2\theta+ br\sin\theta+i(cr^2 \sin\theta\cos\theta+ r\cos\theta)$
The cauchy-Rieman equations for polar coordinates are
$\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{r}}=\frac{1}{r}\times\frac{\partial{v}}{\partial{\theta}}$
$\frac{\partial{v}}{\partial{r}}=\frac{-1}{r}\times\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{\theta}}$
The derivatives are,
$\frac{\partial{v}}{\partial{\theta}}=cr^2\cos2\theta-r\sin\theta\\$
$\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{r}}=2ra\cos2\theta+b\sin\theta\\$

So we get,$2ra\cos2\theta+b\sin\theta=cr\cos2\theta-\sin\theta$

And,
$\frac{\partial{v}}{\partial{r}}=2rc\sin\theta\cos\theta+\cos\theta$
$\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{\theta}}=-4r^2a\sin\theta\cos\theta+br\cos\theta\\$
We get,
$2rc\sin\theta\cos\theta+\cos\theta=4ra\sin\theta\cos\theta-b\cos\theta\\$

I don't know what to do after this or how to solve. I have tried my best but the the equating part is confusing.Here after equating I got $a=\frac{c}{2}$ and $b=-1$. Since the question is to find the real constants we should get a real numbers for a and c right? So what to do now?
My previous question was wrong and sorry for that.

Comment: @AnneBauval sorry, my mistake,I wrote in my notebook as $ra\cos2\theta$ but actual first term is $r^2a\cos2\theta$. I'm still confused at the equating part could you please help me?

Comment: @AnneBauval Yeah, thank you for that, again a doubt mam, could you please help?

Answer (score 0):

Your two conditions
$$2ra\cos2\theta+b\sin\theta=cr\cos2\theta-\sin\theta$$
$$2rc\sin\theta\cos\theta+\cos\theta=4ra\sin\theta\cos\theta-b\cos\theta$$
must hold for every $r,\theta$, so you must just "equate the coefficients", like in [your previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4836077):
$$c=2a,\quad b=-1,$$
as you wrote. There is no other constraint and $a$ may even be any *complex* number. Any function
$$f(z)=r^2a\cos2\theta-r\sin\theta+i(2ar^2 \sin\theta\cos\theta+ r\cos\theta)$$
is analytic and even polynomial, as could be found directly:
$$ar^2(\cos2\theta+2i\sin\theta\cos\theta)+ r(i\cos\theta-\sin\theta)=az^2+iz.$$

Comment: But the question is to find the constants right? So is that ok if we kept it like that?

Comment: Yes: "There is no other constraint and $a$
 may even be any complex number. $f(z)=az^2+iz$ is analytic."